# Why is this Mesh broken up?

Tags: mesh, import

[image]I'm practicing with a mesh body from a game. I'm using XPS to import it into Blender, but the body mesh appears to be separated and not one uniform object. I can't find the mesh listed as an object in the layer tab either- am I uploading it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Importers will separate things into multiple meshes, or even multiple separate objects. It looks like the mesh in the picture is still one object, but the mesh has been "cut" along various seams. First thing to try, in Edit mode, select the entire mesh, open the space-bar search, and and find the "Remove Doubles" tool. You may have to adjust the merge distance option, depending on the size of your mesh.

Comment: not sure that's the right tool to use to get these 2 pieces back together. Keeping the merge distance as low as possible, it doesn't appear to have an effect- pieces are still separate. When I raise it to 0.1, the leg start to collapse in on itself. If I convert it to an object and join the pieces, I can edit them both simultaneously, but they're still separated.

Comment: *I also tried merging the overlapping vertices but the areas still register separate.

Comment: Is the mesh in the picture one object, or multiple?

Comment: I imported this from an xps file so I'm not sure, the obj wasn't showing up. So I exported it as an object and re-imported it to find 2 objects, the groupings you see.

Comment: Ok. In that case, from Object Mode, select both objects and press ctrl+J to join them into one object. Then try my suggestion above.

Comment: I did but there's still seams :l

Comment: Can you post the .blend file?

Comment: oh! I found out what it was! The blue lines were an indicator that it's "marked as sharp"- so I unmarked it! Whew, that was a small fix and a rough learning experience lol thank you for your help with merging the mesh Andy <3